# Why does the MSI Setup ask for reboot on update?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation, reboot

We receive the following message if we run an update of our software. The Setup was build with the WiX Toolset.

The setup contains a Windows service. The service is stopped from the setup before files are copied, but after this message. Final there is no reboot needed. Why does this message occur then? How can we prevent this?

[image: MSI reboot message]

Here the service declaration:

```
<Component Guid="xxx" Id="service">
    <File Id="Service.exe" Name="Service.exe" Source="C:\xxx\prunsrv.exe"/>
    <ServiceInstall Arguments=" foo" Description="xyz" DisplayName="foo Server" ErrorControl="normal" Id="service_install" Name="foo-server" Start="auto" Type="ownProcess"/>
    <ServiceControl Id="service_start" Name="foo-server" Remove="uninstall" Start="install" Stop="both"/>
</Component>
```

Answer (score 2):

When it says "....files or services..." that's just a generic message. It doesn't mean your service is causing this.

Do the install while taking a verbose log, and look for things like 1603 messages that refer to in-use files and see if you can track the files down.

What often happens is that Windows checks and sees it will need to replace some files that are in use at that time. That's why it says "...choose to continue...". But when it gets to actually replace those files it finds they are no longer in use, so a reboot is not necessary. So it's a timing thing.

I'm wondering if you have suppressed the FilesInUse dialogs because it's common for Windows Installer to tell you what processes you need to stop to avoid a reboot. So it's almost as if you have suppressed FilesInUse dialogs, and so the InstallValidate detects some in-use files and gives you that generic messsage about reboots. However by the time it gets to replace those files, perhaps many minutes, they are no longer in use, so they can be replaced without a reboot.

Anyway, that FilesInUse comment is speculation without more information, but the reason the reboot doesn't happen is that the files were no longer in use when it was time to physically replace them.

Comment: I does not thing that I have disable FilesInUse. I simple use <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir"/>